# Can Methane be converted into Carbon and Two Hydrogen Atoms?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Can methane be converted into carbon and two Hydrogen Atoms?I have searched the internet for an answer to this question, and this is never discussed.

If possible can this be done easily and with how much energy?

Comment: Carbon and two hydrogen atoms is not a thing at all (a transient intermediate, at best), so what's the question?

Comment: Now you have clarified the question, the answer is yes. But it isn't a bulk process. CVD deposition of diamond (pure carbon) is done by reacting a plasma containing methane and hydrogen with a suitable surface. In effect, this converts methane into carbon (as a diamond film on the surface) and hydrogen.

Answer (score 1):

There is no double bond in methane, maybe you are referring to ethene? Alkenes have double bonds, not alkanes. And moreover there is no possibly way for methane to have double bonds as the most stable form of it is CH4.

Now if you are just concerned with the breaking of C=C double bonds then the process is quite common in the transformation of organic compounds, and the energy required to do so is 614kJ/mol

Answer (score -4):

There is no double bond in Methane. A double bond is written as two lines in between symbols and methane has a single carbon atom with single bonds to 4 hydrogen atoms. Methane can be split under the right conditions though. The carbon is mostly left behind during that process. If your talking about a double bond it would be written as:

```
C=C
```

Not

```
C-H
```

A double bond between carbon and hydrogen probably would not happen.

Comment: A double bond can be split though